# How to specify 'includes' for nested properties in a document in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to use RavenDB's REST API to make some calls to my database and I'm wondering if there's a way to use the 'includes' feature to return documents that are nested in a document.

For example, I have an object, `Order`, that looks similar to this:

```
    "Order": {
      "Lines": [
        {
          "Product": "products/11-A"
        },
        {
          "Product": "products/42-A"
        },
        {
          "Product": "products/72-A"
        }
      ],
      "OrderedAt": "1996-07-04T00:00:00.0000000",
      "Company": "companies/85-A"
    }
```

`Company` maps to another document and is simple enough to include in the query.

```
{ "Query": "from Orders include Company" }
```

My problem is `Product` that is nested in `Lines`, which is an array of order lines. Since I didn't find anything in the documentation about it I tried things like `include Product` or `include Lines.Product`, but those didn't work.

Is this kind of thing possible with the REST API? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to **Query for Related Documents** from the client can be found in this [demo](https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/query-related-documents):
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/query-related-documents

The matching **RQL to be used** in the Query when using REST API is:

```
from 'Orders' include 'Lines[].Product'
```

Comment: Awesome, that RQL snippet worked perfectly. tysm! Wish there were examples of this in the docs.

Comment: https://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RDoc-2224